# Https request without ssl verification in react

Tags: reactjs, ssl, flask, https

There are a lot of questions and answers on how to make an https request without ssl verification. My problem is that I am accessing a local device’s Webserver (something like https://10.8.8.8:5000/info) to retrieve some information from my reactjs web application. The ssl certificates from the device are not public trusted CA and will never be (it is a python flask Webserver with adhoc ssl configuration). Still I want to access the https resource from my reactjs app and process the resulting json.

I saw many posts to use rejectUnauthorized but until now I did not have success with that.

What is best solution to my problem and best practices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code :-

```
import os
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ""
```

Comment: You mean in python (flask)? Could you give me a bit of background information on this approach? Thanks